# how do I find a tag with simple_html_DOM

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

Im trying to use [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) with php to parse a webpage with this tag:

```
<div class="  row  result" id="p_a8a968e2788dad48" data-jk="a8a968e2788dad48" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting" data-tn-component="organicJob">
```

where data-tn-component="organicJob" is the identifier I want to parse based on, I cant seem to specify the text in a way that simple_html_dom recognizes.

Ive tried a few things along this line:

```
<?PHP
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$f="http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Electrician&l=maine";
    $html->load_file($f);
        foreach($html->find('div[data-tn-component="organicJob"]') as $div)
              {
                 echo  $div->innertext ;
               }
?>
```

but the parser doesn't find any of the results, even though i know they are there. Probably I'm not making specifying the thing I find correctly.
I'm looking at [the API](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm), but I still don't understand how to format the find string.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is correct but i see other problems in your code

1) you are missing `.php` in your include `include 'simple_html_dom';` it should be

```
include '/absolute_path/simple_html_dom.php';
```

2) to load content through url use `file_get_html` function instead `$html->load_file($f);` which is wrong as php don't know that `$html` is simple_html_dom object

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
// then only call 
$html->find( ...
```

3) in your provided link: http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Electrician+Helper&l=maine there is no present element with `data-tn-component` attribute

so final code should be

```
include '/absolute_path/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Electrician&l=maine');

$html->load_file($f);
foreach($html->find('div[data-tn-component="organicJob"]') as $div)
{
    echo  $div->innertext ;
}
```

Comment: I had a typo with the include, the actual code has an array of listings, i should have checked to makesure the one I selected was a valid listing, with that tag.  even so, Im still not sure what should come after $html->find(...

Comment: I updated my answer with final code, take attention on point 2) regarding whot to correctly load initial content